# Customers are weird these days

Tags: riddle, story, board-games

It's been a slow day at *The Board Game Store™* when the familiar ring of a bell brings you back from your daydreaming, alerting you to the presence of a customer.  You look over and notice the oddest customer you think you've ever had.  They're wearing fuzzy bunny slippers, a majestic horse shirt, a long necklace with some kind of red fish, and what appears to be an elephant hat with huge ears and a long trunk.

Not wanting to be rude, you begin talking with the newcomer. "*Hello!  Is there anything I can help you find?*".  The customer walks up to the counter and smiles.

> *I'm looking for a board game for 2 to play.
>
>   The key is the rabbits, or so they say.*
>
> *The board is a grid, similar to the checker.
>
>   Beware the traps, though, unless you have a protector.*
>
> *There's natural enemies, like the cats and the dogs.
>
>   Some frozen in fear, like a petrified log.*

You respond, "*You speak as if you're the Cat in the Hat!  Pardon me please, I must look in the back.*"  As you scour the shelves, you don't find the game they want.  You grab the alternative and bring it back to the front.  "*I could not find the game you requested.  We have plenty of these, though, and it can work as a perfect substitute.*"

The customer agrees to accept your suggestion, agreeing that it will work perfectly, and says they'll be back later to pick up the official game.

**What did you give them and what are you going to order?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the board game

> Arimaa

Which is played with

> Rabbits (slippers), Cats(Cat in the Hat), Dogs, Horses(shirt), Camels, and Elephants(hat). Unfortunately, it lacks Red Herrings (necklace), but that's probably because it's played on land.

```
I'm looking for a board game for 2 to play.
The key is the rabbits, or so they say.
```

> 2 players, and You win by getting a rabbit to the opponent's home row, or by killing all of your opponent's rabbits.

```
The board is a grid, similar to the checker.
Beware the traps, though, unless you have a protector.
```

> Played on a 8x8 board, you lose pieces by having them on "Trap" squares without a neighboring ally.

```
There's natural enemies, like the cats and the dogs.
```

> Cats and Dogs are among 6 piece types each player has

```
Some frozen in fear, like a petrified log.
```

> Animals are frozen if they have a stronger Enemy neighbor, and no Allied neighbor.

You gave them

> A Chess set, which has the same board (mostly, traps missing from C3, C6, F3, and F6) and pieces in the same distribution.

Comment: There's also a few clues in the "story" bit if you want to find everything.